# Playing movies from Android OS off SD/memory card

Tags: laptop, video, android, sd-card, battery-life

I have been doing some reading about running android OS from the BOOT menu using an SD/memory card in my laptop. For the purposes of watching movies on a long flight, for example, would loading the movie to the card as well as using the Android OS and app to play the movie, significantly extend my battery life. Since the drive uses less power than the traditional drive? Also, here I am assuming that by Booting from the Memory card my normal HD will be inactive, therefore off and not consuming any power. Are these safe assumptions?

Answer (score 0):

No it's unlikely to extend your battery life and most likely shorten it. Android might be a very lightweight OS and more then powerful enough to handle the playback it wasn't designed for x86 architecture and to be used on laptop so I would suspect it would eat your battery.

I would suggest seeking out another lightweight linux distro built for computers and using it in the same manner you were suggesting as it would more likely know how to perform correct power management on a laptop.

I terms of the your internal HDD power usage it's going to be between 4-8 watts of power usage and if it's plugged in and not being used it might use maybe .5 watts less but will still draw power.